# Alamofire Swift 5 : Throws an error while passing parameter

Tags: ios, swift, parameter-passing, alamofire

My parameter value looks like this when it gets printed in the console due to which I get an error :

> failure(Alamofire.AFError.responseSerializationFailed(reason:
>   Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(error:
>   Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around
>   character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around
>   character 0.})))

```
["preparation_method[]": "[{\"method_stage\":\"0\",\"method_description\":\"This is test methof1\"}]", "recipe_id": "10454", "ingredients[]": "[{\"ingredient_unit_id\":\"Cup\",\"ingredient_item_id\":\"1\",\"ingredient_item\":\"Rice\",\"ingredient_remark\":\"\",\"ingredient_qty\":\"1\"},{\"ingredient_unit_id\":\"\",\"ingredient_item_id\":\"2\",\"ingredient_item\":\"\",\"ingredient_remark\":\"\",\"ingredient_qty\":\"\"},{\"ingredient_unit_id\":\"\",\"ingredient_item_id\":\"3\",\"ingredient_item\":\"\",\"ingredient_remark\":\"\",\"ingredient_qty\":\"\"}]"]
```

the format in which the parameter should look like is given below:

```
["recipe_id" : "10454", 
ingredients[]: [{"ingredient_unit_id":"Cup","ingredient_item_id":"1","ingredient_item":"Rice","ingredient_remark":"","ingredient_qty":"1"},
{"ingredient_unit_id":"","ingredient_item_id":"2","ingredient_item":"","ingredient_remark":"","ingredient_qty":""},
{"ingredient_unit_id":"","ingredient_item_id":"3","ingredient_item":"","ingredient_remark":"","ingredient_qty":""}],
 preparation_method[] : 
[{"method_stage":"0","method_description":"This is test methof1"}] ]
```

The code I have used is

```
let arr = ingredient.map({ Model(ingredient_item: $0,
                                  ingredient_item_id: $1,
                                  ingredient_qty: $2,
                                  ingredient_unit_id: $3,
                                  ingredient_remark: $4)})

        let jsonData = try! JSONEncoder().encode(arr)
        let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)
        let ingredientstring = jsonString?.replacingOccurrences(of: "'\'" , with: "")
        let ingredientarrayvalue = "\(ingredientstring!)"
        print(ingredientarrayvalue)
        let ingredient_array = String(ingredientarrayvalue)


        let arr1 = prepatation.map({ Model1(method_stage: $0,
                                  method_description: $1)})

        let jsonData1 = try! JSONEncoder().encode(arr1)
        let jsonString1 = String(data: jsonData1, encoding: .utf8)
        let preparationstring = jsonString1?.replacingOccurrences(of: "'\'" , with: "")
        let preparationarrayvalue = "\(preparationstring!)"
        print(preparationarrayvalue)
        let preparation_array = String(preparationarrayvalue)


        let parameter = ["recipe_id" : recipevalue, "ingredients[]" : ingredient_array, "preparation_method[]" : preparationarrayvalue]
        print(parameter)

 let url = RECIPE.recipeSAVEURL
  AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameter).responseJSON(completionHandler: {response in

            print(response)
            if let response_data = response.value as? NSDictionary{

                let responsestatus = response_data.value(forKey: "response") as! String
                print(responsestatus)

                if responsestatus == "success"{
                }
            }
        })
```

How can I pass the parameter without "\" in the parameter?Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

After tiring hours of searching for a solution to my above question, I came across the following github link : https://gist.github.com/cprovatas/5c9f51813bc784ef1d7fcbfb89de74fe

Where they uses an extension for data and I applied it as following in my code :

```
let preparation_array = jsonString1!.data(using: .utf8)!.prettyPrintedJSONString!
let ingredient_array = jsonString!.data(using: .utf8)!.prettyPrintedJSONString!
```

the copy of the extension code used in the link mentioned above is given below for reference, if any:

```
extension Data {
    var prettyPrintedJSONString: NSString? { /// NSString gives us a nice sanitized debugDescription
        guard let object = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: self, options: []),
              let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: object, options: [.prettyPrinted]),
              let prettyPrintedString = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) else { return nil }

        return prettyPrintedString
    }
}

let str = "{\"foo\": \"bar\"}".data(using: .utf8)!.prettyPrintedJSONString!
debugPrint(str)
```

/* prints:
     {
        "foo" : "bar"
     }